# Multiply array elements without using loop

Tags: arrays, recursion, multiplication

If I have array a[]={2,3,5} resultant array should be {(2*3)6,(2*5)10,(3*5)15}.
You can not use loop. This can be solves using recursion,but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Loops can be mechanically transformed into recursion, not that it does you much good..

Comment: @harold It is not about productivity. This is about problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively multiply an array.

```
void multiply(double[] a, double[] b, index){
    if(index==a.length){
        return;
    }
    a[index] = a[index]*b[index];
    multiply(a, b, index+1);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted the example from the question to be processed, what parameter would I supply to `multipl(a, b, index)`? What would be the result? What is `multiply()`?

Comment: @greybeard multiply is the method described above, it is calling itself and that is what makes it recursive. Your example doesn't have enough information. The first element is `(2*3)6` for most mathematical notations that means 2*3*6? Let's say it isn't, are the elements all of the combinations? Do they have to be in order?

Comment: `multiply is the method described above` then why does the declaration read `multipl()`? `Your example doesn't have enough information` well observed but for the example being [user1547535](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1547535/user1547535)'s rather than mine. (And that observation might call for a comment on the question rather than for an answer. If it was me, I'd call for the_products of all pairs with the 1st index smaller than the 2nd in lexicographical order_.)

Comment: `why does the declaration read multipl()` type-o, fixed. Thanks. Although the ops question definitely needs some clarification. If it is as you say, eg. {a, b, c} => {a\*b, a\*c, b\*c}, then one would expect {a, b, c, d} => {a\*b, a\*c, a\*d, b\*c, b\*d, c\*d}; Which means the resulting array, the length needs to be set at some point. (n-1)\*(n-2), which is a little odd for a recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int multiply1(int n, int left, int right)
{

    if(left==(n-1))
        return 1;

    //System.out.print(arr[left]+" ");
    //System.out.print(arr[right]+" ");
    System.out.println(arr[left]*arr[right]);
    right++;
    if(right==n)
    {
        left++;
        right=left+1;
    }
    multiply1(n, left, right);
    //arr1[start]=arr[ind]*arr[next];
    //multiply1(start+1, ind, next+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (While I have a hard time discerning what the question asks:) What does this post answer, and what is the `resultant array`? (The comment `//arr1[start]=arr[ind]*arr[next];` uses non-pertaining names.)

Comment: Resultant array is [6,10,15]